# Use SendInput() to input Greek letters

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a program in C++, that takes the characters from a given string and simulates the button presses of each character using the SendInput() command. It works fine with ASCII characters such as Latin letters and standard symbols, but it doesn't work with unicode characters, specifically I'm trying to type in Greek. For example instead of printing the Greek letter 'Σ' it prints this character, which looks like Japanese 'ﾑ'. Can anyone please explain why this happens and how can I fix it?
This is my function for each keystroke:

```
void Press(char c)
{
      INPUT in;
      in.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      in.ki.wVk = 0;
      in.ki.wScan = c;
      in.ki.time = 0;
      in.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
      in.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

      INPUT i[] = { in };
      SendInput(1, i, sizeof(in));

}
```

Comment: Probably the way forward is to solve the actual problem without resorting to faking input

Comment: You are passing a `char`, which can only encode ANSI characters, not Unicode characters. You'll have to pass a `wchar_t` instead.

Comment: And you have to pass 2 `wchar_t` values, each one in its own `INPUT` structure, if the desired Unicode codepoint is large enough to require use of a UTF-16 surrogate pair. So it would be better to have `Press()` accept a `wchar_t*`/`std::wstring` string that you loop through, instead of accepting a single `wchar_t` character.